# Windows 10 boot menu only gives me 'turn pc off' option

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop (with Windows 10 already installed). I have my USB bootable by downloading Ubuntu 16.04 from their torrent file (because the direct one was taking ages to download). I have also done disk partitioning and have 45 GB unallocated space at the moment. When I tried to enter into boot menu using

1. Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and Restart Option
2. Going through Update and Security method I did get the blue boot screen option but I only got one option: "Turn PC Off". I didn't get any other options through which I could install Ubuntu through bootable USB Drive!

Answer (score 0):

What did you use to make it bootable? I'd suggest [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/download) for ease of use. The `.iso` you downloaded needs to be specially unpacked to the USB and made bootable.

After that, you ought to be able to press <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, or <kbd>F12</kbd> to get something to pop up when booting/rebooting. You may need to enter the BIOS and specifically set the boot order or boot device or even to enable USB booting. This differs for every PC/Laptop.